# Enabling intel virtualization (VT-X) without option in BIOS

Tags: android, intel, virtualization, bios, haxm

Sorry if the question is already answered, but I haven't found answer for my particular situation, that is a little different.

I'm installing all the tools necessary for android programming. I have created an android virtual device, but the problem come installing intel hardware acceleration (HAXM), the installer say to me I need activate VT-x and it seems that this tool only can be activated in BIOS, but my BIOS is InsydeH20 rev 3.5 and the option doesn't appear anywhere.

What can I do? How can I activate VT-x without BIOS?

My processor is intel i7 2630qm, I have check in the intel page if my processor is compatible with VT-x and yes it is.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Most of motherboards has enabled VT-x support by default even this options not in bios. I have simmilar problem. Main point was that I have antivirus that use virtualization for sandbox(Avast anti virus). SO I delete avast, install HAXM and after that install avast again. All work. Try to find what software use virtualization on your computer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can run some bcedit commands from the command line to set ND Bit and VT
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off 
bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn 
Also do the install from https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager 
If you're using Avast, disable "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" under: Settings > Troubleshooting. Restart the PC and try to run the HAXM installation again

(instead of using the one downloaded through

Comment: HAXM was the key for me. Can't understand why but it works. It works!! Thank you

Comment: I don't think this solution enables virtualisation, it just disables other hypervisors (e.g. Hyper-V or antivirus) which might conflict with HAXM. Therefore this only works if virtualisation is already enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I looked and looked in the BIOS but couldn't find a virtualization entry, so then I searched and read for many hours, finally finding this post.

The other answer didn't work for me so just before posting a comment (that I figured would not be seen for a year or two) I booted into my BIOS once more and thought, since I also have InsydeH20, I would confirm that there is no entry there.  Low and behold I had overlooked the tiny menu bar at the top.  Under the 3rd option (System Configuration) I finally stumbled on the entry  I was looking for:

```
virtualization  <disabled>
```

After changing that to enabled and rebooting I was *finally* able to see the 64-bit options in VirtualBox.

My computer:

- HP Pavillion M7
- i7-3610QM
- 8GB RAM
- BIOS=InsydeH20
- Win 10 Home

I should note, virtualization still shows disabled in the performance tab of the task manager, but Virtualbox works just fine.

Comment: For me under Rev 5.0 of InsydeH20 it was under the "Configuration" tab and the option was named "Intel Virtual Technology"